# How to add file filter for JFileChooser

Tags: java, excel, jfilechooser, filechooser

I want to select only .xls and .xlsx file but I am unable to select any type of file. Can anybody suggest me any code or can anybody make changes in my existing code ? 
Thanks in advance.

```
    public class Convertor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
        chooser.setDialogTitle("choosertitle");
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

        if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
          System.out.println("getCurrentDirectory(): " + chooser.getCurrentDirectory());
          System.out.println("getSelectedFile() : " + chooser.getSelectedFile());
        } else {
          System.out.println("No Selection ");
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use [FileNameExtensionFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html).

```
 FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Excel file", "xls", "xlsx");
 chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Improving @Amila's comment, it should be something like this:

```
 FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Excel files", "xlsx", "xls");
 fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);            
 fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use FileFilter class.

```
class ExcelFilter extends FileFilter {

@Override
public boolean accept(File pathname) {
  String filename = pathname.getName();
  if (pathname.isDirectory()) {
    return true;

  } else if (filename.endsWith("xls") || filename.endsWith("xlsx")) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

@Override
public String getDescription() {
  return "Excel Files";
}
}
```

Now in your main class use:

```
chooser.setFileFilter(new ExcelFilter());
```